# CSS: how to make a horizontal images scroller with two images per column?

Tags: css

I have an horizontal images scroller, like this:
[image: scroller with single images]

This the markup:

```
<div class="slider-horizontal">
  <span ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a href="#">
      <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

And this the style:

```
.slider-horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

No, I would like to add a secondary image *below* any of the current ones, to obtain something like this:

[image: scroller with double images]

(N.B.: of course nor persons nor the discount label are the real images... :-)

Is it possible? What would you suggest? I can't manage it, all of my trials end up with all of the images on the same row, or all on the same column... :-(

To reply to @rednaw comment: this is what I did try:

```
<div class="slider-horizontal">
  <span ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a href="#">
      <img ng-src="{{image}}" />
      <img src="images/watermarks/label.png" />
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

(whith not great success, as I said... :-()

Comment: show the code that you tried

Comment: see the update to the question...

Comment: You should probably make those images use the `:after` pseudo selector, so you're not trying to balance two inline elements next to each other.  The other option would be to wrap them in `divs` and set the display to `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

Did u try something like this

```
<div class="slider-horizontal">
  <span class="slider-image" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a href="#">
      <img ng-src="{{image}}" /><br>
      <img src="myimg.jpg" />
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slider-image {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the first user + label are fine, but the second user (and following) appear next to the previous label, non next to the previous user...

Comment: ok try adding a class slider image to span and try those css changes once. and let me know the result

Comment: Hmmm... no, I get something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2_jr4LK_91dc2R0ekVtWDgzZHM/view?usp=sharing :-(((

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!!! It works (I just forgot to save style.css file in editor :-() Thanks. Problem solved, answer accepted.